# Restrict access to Task Scheduler for non-admin users

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

In Windows 7, is it possible (via regedit, cmd, gpedit.msc, or any other manner) to restrict access to Task Scheduler for non-admin users (i.e, unruly children)?

By restricting access, I mean:

- prevent a user from creating a task
- prevent a user from accessing taskschd.msc via Start menu, or directly

If it's possible, how can I achieve it?

I have tried:

- accessing the registry, by going to `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-non-admin-user-id\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` and creating a REG_DWORD called NoTaskScheduler, with the value of 1
- changing the REG_DWORD name to Notaskschd.msc, then to Notaskschd, then to Taskschd.msc, etc, but that did nothing as well
- going to `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-non-admin-user-id\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System`, and repeating the process

***EDIT*** Additional info (maybe it's relevant) - The user(s) who are now standard users used to be administrators before. I have since revoked their rights, and now they're standard users.

Using Local Group Policy Editor to restrict Task Scheduler access amounts to nothing.

Comment: Did you already see this or try these suggestion per Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305612/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-running-task-scheduler-in-windows. Let me know if you want me to add as an answer but this should suffice I would think based on your detail. Easy enough to try, test, and confirm though so take a stab at it <::;;::;;::;;[|||||||}o

Comment: Doesn't task scheduler already require admin privileges to create and/or modify tasks?

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator: Forgot to mention - that was one of the first things I tried. It does nothing - even after enabling all the prohibitions, the standard user can still access the Scheduler, add new tasks, delete existing ones, etc. The registry edit also did nothing. The standard user wasn't logged in at the time, nor was there any remaining session, at least according to ``query session <username>``. :|

Comment: @LPChip: I would expect so. The standard user was an administrator before (had to be, because of Xampp and similar programs), but now there's no need for that user to be an administrator, so I've revoked his rights. Maybe that has something to do with it.